# Local image not showing (react-native-expo-image-cache)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

**why local image not showing?**

import {Image} from "react-native-expo-image-cache";

```
const uri =
  image && image.length
    ? `${URL_IMG}${image[0]?.s_path}${image[0]?.pk_i_id}.${image[0]?.s_extension}`
    :  ("../assets/No_Image_Available.jpg");

    

        <Image style={styles.image} {...{ uri }} />
```

package url  https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-expo-image-cache

Comment: check what you are returning from `uri`. Does it only not work if `image && image.length` is true?

Comment: url return ../assets/No_Image_Available.jpg

Comment: you must make sure that the file is in the correct directory or configure the static path of files correctly